# How to break a String by whitespace

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a String in a JSP

```
var="abcd efgh ijkl pqrs";
```

i am getting this string from a request attribute in a  jsp.
i want to break this string by whitespace and strored in a variable.
for example: 
`var newValue="abcd";
var newValue="efgh";`
and want to use this value for other purpose.
`document.getElementsByID("ID["+newValue+"]";`
i want to do this in javascript in a jsp.
please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you researched and tried any solution yet?

Comment: I have a String:
var newValue="abcd efgh ijkl pqrs";
and want to use its value in calling other thing.
document.getElementsByID("ID["+abcd+"]";
document.getElementsByID("ID["+efgh+"]";
document.getElementsByID("ID["+ijkl +"]";
document.getElementsByID("ID["+pqrs+"]";
please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str= "abcd efgh ijkl pqrs";
var arr = str.split(" ");
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
 alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Read up on the `String.split` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split();`

**Example**

```
document.getElementByID(IDOFDOME).val.split(' ');
```